# Should SessionId be sent via GET or POST?

Tags: javascript, post, get, e-commerce, sessionid

For an ecommerce related client application that performs web scraping, and then passes product related information as well as a SessionId to the backend... is it okay to send the SessionId as part of the URL (i.e. GET) even though the remaining information is sent via a POST? Or should all the data, including the SessionId be sent via a POST?

The site http://www.seochat.com/c/a/search-engine-optimization-help/preventing-duplicate-content-on-an-e-commerce-site-from-session-ids/
seems to use GET for sending SessionId. Is that a standard?

Comment: A sessionId could be stored in a cookie and sent as part of all requests.

Comment: Are you asking about php session id ? If so, it is automatically sent with the request header.

Comment: Not a PHP SessionId, it will be a randomly generated parameter sent via javascript.

Comment: If your requirement is to authenticate the user, It is always better to use PHP $_SESSION variable.

Comment: There is no php involved. Like I said... it is just a simple html and javascript front end application.

Comment: Now I understood. Send it along with POST. All data in POST are secure than GET.

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific standard about it but session id is an information that is sensitive so its definitely not sent by GET. Although post seems to be a better option here but http headers are the right answer here. Headers are basically used for these kind of information i.e. metadata of the request.

Headers are meant to be used for exchanging request meta-data so if we go by standard then headers are the best option here. Follow [microsoft rest api guidelines](https://github.com/Microsoft/api-guidelines) for standard practices

Comment: This site seems to suggest using GET http://www.seochat.com/c/a/search-engine-optimization-help/preventing-duplicate-content-on-an-e-commerce-site-from-session-ids/.

Comment: well if you just want to track visitors from session id then put wherever you want because its not a sensitive information but if you manage logins and other things using session ids then request headers is the right choice